# How to ssh to the controller in Juju 2.0?

Tags: juju

When I list the machines, it doesn't list the controller machine. How do I ssh to the controller machine? Using 2.0-beta15

Answer (score 4):

Juju 2.0 supports multiple models in a single controller. When you bootstrap, Juju creates two models: "controller", and "default". When bootstrap completes, the client will switch to the default model. The controller machines are all within the controller model.

So, to SSH to a controller machine, you need to operate within the controller model. You can switch to it first using "juju switch controller", or you can use "-m controller" to specify the model without switching to it for future commands. e.g.

```
juju ssh -m controller 0
```